# Add a title to the graph generated using the R circlize package

Tags: r, circlize

How can I added a title to the circos plot generated using the circlize package, please? I didn't find any reference in the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, title is not mentioned in the manual. On the other hand, if you study the excellent [`circlize` vignette](http://zuguang.de/circlize_book/book/) (it's actually [a book](http://zuguang.de/circlize_book/book/circlize-book.pdf) of 171 pages!), you find that:

> [circlize is built on the `base` R graphic system](http://zuguang.de/circlize_book/book/graphics.html#work-with-base-graphic-system), then, of course the `base` graphic functions can be used in combination with circlize functions. [...]
>
> Normally, the base functions such as `title()`, `text()`, `legend()` can be used to add extra information on the plot

Thus, just add `title()` after your `circlize` plot call.